Insert a tag in the serialization of an xml file
I am serializing an XML file with the classes created automatically with paste special of an XML. I did everything without problems, more than 3,000 lines (and the Xml file more than 600), but I have a tag that I can't serialize.
In the original xml file I have this:
<sdtc:statusCode code="active"/>

This is the class generated by Visual Studio:
public string code
{
    get { return this.codeField; }
    set { this.codeField = value; }
}

I serialize it like this:
statusCode oStatusCode = new statusCode();
oStatusCode.code = "active";

And this is the serialized result:
<statusCode code="active" />

As you can see, the sdtc: prefix is missing and I don't know how to insert it.
I tried with:
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:hl7-org:sdtc")]

but it has no effect. I searched for hours but couldn't find a solution. Unfortunately, this is my first experience with serialization.
Any ideas or suggestions?
EDIT:
Since the serialization classes are more than 12,000 lines long, I don't think I can insert them, I'll try to insert something useful, hope I'm not wrong.
First line of XML file:
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:mif="urn:hl7-org:v3/mif" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:lab="urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.3.2" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc">

The first lines of serializer code:
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3", IsNullable = false)]


How are you serializing your type to XML?  Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] as indicated by [ask]?  We need to see a complete (possibly simplified) sample of the XML you want to generate + the types you have created that should serialize to the required XML.  Thanks!

In the element <sdtc:statusCode code="active"/>, sdtc: is not a suffix, it's an XML  namespace prefix.  It's possible the prefix was omitted because the corresponding namespace is currently the default namespace, but I can't say for certain without a [mcve].  But possibly XML Serialization and namespace prefixes may help.

The following may be of interest: InvalidOperationException when deserializing custom XML (lack of namespace)

I have now tried to insert some more information, but I don't think inserting the Xml file with over 600 lines or the classes with over 3000 lines is possible.

@Paco - that's not quite enough for us to help you.  We're going to see 1) A class containing the code property.  You can remove all the other properties, but leave all the XmlSerializer attributes applied to the class & property. 2) If that class is not the root class, a root class that refers to the code class with all the XML serialization attributes.  Again properties that are not relevant can be removed.  3) The XML you want to generate for that model but currently cannot.

Since the serialization classes are more than 12,000 lines long, I don't think I can insert them: A post can be up to 30,000 characters long. That limitation applies to answers. I'm not sure whether or not the limitation applies to original posts. Nonetheless, the longer your post the less likely it is to appeal to a majority of people.

I don't think inserting the Xml file with over 600 lines or the classes with over 3000 lines is possible: Many programs have code that well exceeds 3000 lines. While you may not desire to read through all of the lines, it's certainly possible to do. The most successful people in life are the ones who were willing to do what others weren't willing to do.

The URL to the post I provided above gives you everything you need to solve your issue. You should create a minimal, reproducible example which you can use for testing to ensure that you understand how to use namespaces. A minimal, reproducible example can also be posted here should you encounter difficulties so others can use it to re-create the issue.

This is my first experience with the serializer but having to solve the problem I used this solution, certainly incorrect and inelegant, but it works.
        string cRead = File.ReadAllText("mycda.xml");
        System.Xml.Linq.XDocument xdoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(cRead);           
        string cNew = xdoc.ToString();
        cNew = cNew.Replace("<statusCode code=\"activemod\" />", "<sdtc:statusCode code=\"active\" />");

(I use the activemod value to distinguish it from all the others)

Did you use an AI, such as ChatGPT for this?

Yes, but it didn't solve my problem.

I don't understand why -1, but thanks anyway
